# Rake::TestTask is not working inside another task

Tags: ruby, minitest, rake-task

We have developed few test cases using  mini-test / ruby 
Now we are trying to run it using rake files.
its working fine if we are running below code.

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|   
    t.test_files = FileList['../Home/*TC1.rb'] 
    t.verbose = true  
end
```

But we are putting the above code in separate task then id does not run the test

```
task :myCustom_task do 
  Rake::TestTask.new do |t|   
    t.test_files = FileList['../Home/*TC1.rb']         
    t.verbose = true
  end    
end
```

Then we run it by below command

```
rake myCustom_task
```

and it does not run the test.Also it does not show any error while running with --trace option.

What is missing in this approach ?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `TestTask` inside a regular `Task`? It makes no sense.

Comment: we have 5 products and 5 test cases for each product. Sometimes we want to run the test cases for all products and sometimes it is only for one product. To achieve this we want to pass the command line parameter to TestTask. In order to pass command line parameter we are wrapping TestTask inside another task because we did not find any other way to send the command line parameter to Rake::TestTask.

Comment: There are much better ways to run a single test. Minitest has builtin support for running single test files and there are gems that allow you to run a single test from a file.

Comment: Yes I agree that there are other ways to run a single test. But we have different combinations of test cases. Thats why we want to pass the parameter and then build the test_files in rake task and then pass it in TestTask.

Comment: Without being too helpful, is it possible you're not evaluating the directory from where you think?  I would debug the t.test_files value after assignment in both cases and see what's going on.
I would also probably just wuss out and not try to use a test task.
`ruby -Itest...`